# Fourier transform of $\frac{t}{(a^2+t^2)^{3/2}}$.

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-transform, bessel-functions

Im trying to find the Fourier transform of the function:
$$\frac{t}{\left(t^2+a^2\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}};$$
As well the Fourier transform of the function:
$$\frac{1}{\left(t^2+a^2\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}.$$
It looks very similar to the first modified Bessel function but not quite, I wondered if there is an analytic expression for that transformation.

Comment: Latex/MathJax tip: You can format mathematics into the titles as well, though you should only use inline form, i.e. surrounded by single \$ signs, rather than double \$\$ signs.

Comment: These express via $K_0$ and $K_1$, respectively; see [this](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.32#E11).

Comment: The second one is indeed $K_1$ I dont see how the first one gives any of those

Comment: Just integrate by parts (or use the "FT for a derivative" rule, which is the same).

Comment: @Ron Ruimy see my answer here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3747010/proving-a-formula-for-int-x-0-infty-frac-sinaxxx21c-dx-involvi/3747149#3747149