# Proving a formula for $\int_{x=0}^\infty \frac{\sin(ax)x}{(x^2+1)^c} dx$ involving Gamma and Bessel K functions

Tags: integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals, special-functions

In Mathematica,
$$\int_{0}^\infty \frac{\sin(ax)x}{(x^2+1)^c} dx
=\frac{2^{\frac{1}{2}-c}a^{-\frac{1}{2}+c}\pi^{\frac{1}{2}}\operatorname{BesselK}[-\frac{3}{2}+c,a])}{\Gamma[c]} ,$$
where a is a positive real number and $c>\frac{1}{2}.$

I want to prove this, but I can't.

If anyone knows the proof of the above definite integral,
Thank you for your instruction.

Comment: This can be derived from the general formula for the integral of a product of two Meijer G-functions:
$$\frac {\sqrt \pi} {2 \Gamma(c)} \int_0^\infty
 G_{1, 1}^{1, 1} {\left( x \middle| {1 - c \atop 0} \right)}
 G_{0, 2}^{1, 0} {\left( \frac {a^2 x} 4 \middle| {- \atop \frac 1 2, 0} \right)} dx =
\frac {\sqrt \pi} {2 \Gamma(c)}
 G_{1, 3}^{2, 1} {\left( \frac {a^2} 4 \middle| {0 \atop \frac 1 2, c - 1, 0} \right)}.$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a complete solution, but may be one reasonable approach to it.

Firts define:
$$I(a)=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(ax)}{{\left(1+x^{2}\right)}^{c}}dx$$
Which can itself be written in terms of $K_{v}(x)$

Taking the derivative of $I(a)$ with respect to a gives us
$$\frac{dI(a)}{da}=-\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x\sin(ax)}{{\left(1+x^{2}\right)}^{c}}dx$$

Now, consider the following integral, easily verified by a change of variable

$$\Gamma(c)={\left(1+x^{2}\right)}^{c}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-\left(1+x^{2}\right)u} u^{c-1}du$$

now multiply $I(a)$ by $\Gamma(c)$

$$\Gamma(c)I(a)=\int_{0}^{\infty}cos(ax)\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-\left(1+x^{2}\right)u} u^{c-1}dudx$$

Swap the integrals and distribute the exponential

$$\Gamma(c)I(a)=\int_{0}^{\infty}u^{c-1}e^{-u}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x^{2}u}\cos(ax)dxdu$$

The inner integral has the following [solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3746470/determine-int-infty-infty-eipx-qx2-dx/3746507#3746507)

$$\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{u}}e^{-\frac{a^{2}}{4u}}$$

Giving us:

$$\Gamma(c)I(a)=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\int_{0}^{\infty}u^{c-\frac{2}{2}}e^{-u-\frac{a^{2}}{4u}}du$$

Make the following substitution $u=\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)e^{v}$

$$
I(a)=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\frac{1}{\Gamma(c)}{\left(\frac{a}{2}\right)}^{c-\frac{1}{2}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-a\cosh(v)}e^{\left(c-\frac{1}{2}\right)v} dv$$

because $e^{\left(c-\frac{1}{2}\right)v} = \cosh\left(\left(c-\frac{1}{2}\right)v\right)+\sinh\left(\left(c-\frac{1}{2}\right)v\right)$, and since $\sinh\left(\left(c-\frac{1}{2}\right)v\right)$ is an odd function of $v$
gives us the final result:

$$\boxed{I(a)=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\Gamma(c)}{\left(\frac{a}{2}\right)}^{c-\frac{1}{2}}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-a\cosh(v)}\cosh{\left(\left(c-\frac{1}{2}\right)v\right)} dv}$$

$$\boxed{I(a)=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\Gamma(c)}{\left(\frac{a}{2}\right)}^{c-\frac{1}{2}}K_{c-\frac{1}{2}}(x)}$$

The last integral is an Integral representation [2](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.32#E9) of $K_{v}(x)$

Now, take the derivative of this expression with respect to $a$.